# Xamarin - How to quench or filter Application Output?

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin

While making an app in Xamarin I'm using the Application Output" for debugging.
This log gets spam by hundreds of the same message, which I don't want to see.

How can I quench or filter certain messages from appearing in this log?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see only my solution's debug output on Xamarin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679207/how-to-see-only-my-solutions-debug-output-on-xamarin)

Answer (score 5):

Believe it or not but that is not possible to do in Xamarin Application Output widow.  You can do it in Device Monitor.  In Xamarin, go to Tools->Device Monitor and check LogCat.  There you can filter by type of log or by any phrase you want.