# How to see only my solution's debug output on Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I'm making app with using XF pcl.

- Xamarin studio on mac

I'm using Debug.WriteLine for debug.
I want to avoid to see other nuget's console log.

I can see console show my log with blue color.
How to see only blue colored log?

Thanks.

Comment: For the sake of future Users, if the answer solves your issue, please mark it as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Oops Sorry. and thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, it isn't possible to filter Xamarin Studio's Application Output window/log, but according to the following UserVoice page, the community has requested the feature be added.

It would benefit yourself and the community as a whole if you were to go and add your vote to have the feature added.

Here is a link to the feature request page 
- https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-platform-suggestions/suggestions/6301325-application-output-filtering

Comment: Thanks for kind answer!